# Table is not in the current context web api issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to use existing data layer with a web api project it was working before i added the authorisation attribute however now its saying the table is not part of the context I can only persume this is because the username and password store uses a local sql db and not sql server that my entity belong to.

Now i have got the token from a user a setup under the register function which puts it in the local db. So that gave me back the following which i then place in the Authorization header of post man to test the api.

> GET /api/CustomerInfo/B737069E-A835-40EC-BDF7-0CA4821C4D59 HTTP/1.1
>   Host: localhost:54010 
>   Content-Type: application/json Authorization:
>   bearer
>   s159EgZ1KwRvq53eEWeAYTupJlpUGLaDWXTy4Z39ezUX3Ac41HA7v6l3F2uFfW8eJde8eSS-kWKTn05IIkHnIKS-U2IdoaRssS8hZhCAqe9REL8SWFqo92i9kZrbnSMIhC1V73Lt0kMYf_mnjSSFM33OGVe7JHR4-5NUezvO--eI9XtFx6OH5ZCYYmBZo2UhIxt3Ma7jDaFv22c5lx7wrCfL1d2xXgrWTGtWL7QM6mZ18nxncsOT49XFpcEQhAv0a1DRf9ygVZUVYq-L0JSlz_PnZy6YUPuzlzmL0lgcjhTXKYK4f7chI3cIG9Tl96nfn9VxFMQm8XDgxHBWHNFsHp7z3JG9FwGIAtirfiizt-SAmlcXGxxZ0BONHGS18wlMjq_1DkmtGEoz9LQoqn6AdmydGO2fXH2Of-jNR_VCktGvE9D5Uj9PmysU7FNtNtUcoIlYgoTlgPlUnl9k443C1uBU3ZoZCh10Z2wRDoceGMtjFycOW99N00l4fOXGhjmn
>   Cache-Control: no-cache Postman-Token:
>   1fbb870c-af27-aeff-7d36-7520b530c6b8

This is how i have setup barrer token

```
public class CustomerInfoController : ApiController
{
    private portalEntities db = new portalEntities();

    // GET: api/CustomerInfo


    public IQueryable<tblPortalCustomerInfo> GettblPortalCustomerInfoes()
    {
        return db.tblPortalCustomerInfoes;
    }

    // GET: api/CustomerInfo/5

      [Authorize]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GettblPortalCustomerInfo(Guid id)
    {
        tblPortalCustomerInfo tblPortalCustomerInfo = await db.tblPortalCustomerInfoes.FindAsync(id);
        if (tblPortalCustomerInfo == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(tblPortalCustomerInfo);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    [Authorize]
    private bool tblPortalCustomerInfoExists(Guid id)
    {
        return db.tblPortalCustomerInfoes.Count(e => e.id == id) > 0;
    }
}
```

This is the customer info class i am calling

```
public class CustomerInfoController : ApiController
{
    private portalEntities db = new portalEntities();

    // GET: api/CustomerInfo


    public IQueryable<tblPortalCustomerInfo> GettblPortalCustomerInfoes()
    {
        return db.tblPortalCustomerInfoes;
    }

    // GET: api/CustomerInfo/5

      [Authorize]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GettblPortalCustomerInfo(Guid id)
    {
        tblPortalCustomerInfo tblPortalCustomerInfo = await db.tblPortalCustomerInfoes.FindAsync(id);
        if (tblPortalCustomerInfo == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(tblPortalCustomerInfo);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    [Authorize]
    private bool tblPortalCustomerInfoExists(Guid id)
    {
        return db.tblPortalCustomerInfoes.Count(e => e.id == id) > 0;
    }
}
```

Error in post man is 
https://snag.gy/kQYIUP.jpg

> "ExceptionMessage": "The entity type tblPortalCustomerInfo is not
>   part of the model for the current context.",   "ExceptionType":
>   "System.InvalidOperationException",   "StackTrace": "   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type
>   entityType)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.FindAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken, Object[] keyValues)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.FindAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken, Object[] keyValues)\r\n   at
>   System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.FindAsync(Object[] keyValues)\r\n   at
>   portalWebApi.Controllers.CustomerInfoController.<GettblPortalCustomerInfo>d__2.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\\Projects\\Client-Portal\\portalWebApi\\Controllers\\CustomerInfoController.cs:line
>   35\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
>   was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"

Comment: Are you using asp.net Identity? do you use separate context for both backend and security tables?

Comment: @HaithamShaddad the web api 2 template usings identy and the sep context to my own context but waht i dont understand is why it cant find my tables when i use the authorise tag

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to solve this problem:

1. Move the relevant tables from the local DB to the SQL Server and update the existing `EF` model.
2. Create a new `EF` model for the local `DB` and use the new context instead of the existing `portalEntities` context for authenticating users.

Comment: But surley i have my context there this works witghout the authorisation tag and sends data fine but as soon as i add the bearer code it does not how would i go about intergrating the tables.

Comment: can you help as to how to do this